# Al transpolar una variable en Javascript y realizar una operación con la misma, arroja NaN

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, algoritmos, parsear

En este algoritmo, el resultado arroja NaN pero no entiendo el por qué pues se han parseado todos los datos... hice console.log y la variabe sumaAlumnos arroja NaN pero no sé si será el tema de que esté mal planteado el for o quizas alguna otra cosa

```
let cantidadAlumno = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese por favor la cantidad de Alumnos a Registrar:"));
let edades; //Registro de Edades
let sumaAlumnos; //Acomulador de las edades
let n;

for (n = 1; n <= cantidadAlumno; n++){
    edades = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese por favor la edad del alumno " + n));
    sumaAlumnos = sumaAlumnos + edades;
}

alert(`El promedio de las edades de los ${cantidadAlumno} alumnos es: ${sumaAlumnos/cantidadAlumno}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no le estás dando un valor inicial a **sumaAlumnos**, edades no te da problemas porque dentro del `for` estás generando la variable otra vez con el valor del `prompt` y por su **Scope** no afecta a la definición de la variable externa al for.

Si no se hace lo que se conoce como inicializar una variable, su valor es undefined, si intentas sumar undefined + Number ej: undefined + 5, esto devuelve NaN, que es exactamente lo que te está sucediendo, si la inicializamos con el número **0**, la primer suma será 0 + el número, dando como resultado el primer número y luego en cada iteración suma el número depositado en sumaAlumnos + el número ingresado, dando como resultado un correcto funcionamiento.

Reemplazar esto:

```
let sumaAlumnos;
```

Por esto:

```
let sumaAlumnos = 0;
```

Ya sería suficiente.

**Notas:**
La definición de `let edades; //Registro de Edades` no está cumpliendo ninguna función, ya que esta es declarada dentro del `for`.

Y por último la definición de n generalmente se hace dentro del `for` mismo, quedando así:

```
for (let n = 1; n <= cantidadAlumno; n++){....}
```

Dicho esto, el código completo funcional puede ser el siguiente:

```
let cantidadAlumno = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese por favor la cantidad de Alumnos a Registrar:"));
let sumaAlumnos = 0; //Acomulador de las edades

for (let n = 1; n <= cantidadAlumno; n++){
    const edades = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese por favor la edad del alumno " + n));
    sumaAlumnos = sumaAlumnos + edades;
}

alert(`El promedio de las edades de los ${cantidadAlumno} alumnos es: ${sumaAlumnos/cantidadAlumno}`);
```

Espero ayude a resolver tu inconveniente, quedo a las órdenes.